# Vuex Mutation target passed to payload instead of looking for it in the state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Let's say the vuex state has a structure like this:

```
state: {
        houses: [{
            pk: 1,
            historicalName: 'Poo'
        }],
    },
```

And `house` instances from the state are used by passing it as props to components (`houses.vue` template):

```
<div><house v-for="hs in housesState" :house="hs"></house></div>
```

Then when I need to mutate fields of `house`, do I write mutation like this:

```
[Types.mutations.SET_HISTORICAL_NAME]: (state, payload) => {
   state.houses.find(x => x.pk === payload.house.pk).historicalName = payload.historicalName
}
```

or do I pass the instance of the `house` from component

```
this.$store.commit(Types.mutations.SET_HISTORICAL_NAME, {house: this.house, historicalName: 'Gold'})
```

and update it without searching the array?

```
[Types.mutations.SET_HISTORICAL_NAME]: (state, payload) => {
       payload.house.historicalName = payload.historicalName
}
```

Will the second option cause any locks in the state? Mutation could be called simultaneously for different `houses`. Will it be faster? Not searching the array every time should help but I'm not sure it's that straightforward here.

House data is also used by another components (I've simplified data structure in the question) so I don't think I can only store `house` on local component level.

Comment: Your last code example is incorrect in assuming you can access the correct house without the index.  You'll always have to search to find the index or track the index in the component.  I would personally choose your first option of finding the index inside of the store to insure that the indexes don't change on you from a different component or side effect.

Comment: Last code example uses `payload.house` which is sent by component like `{house: this.house, historicalName: 'Gold'}` and component gets it from the store when rendered by `v-for`. Where I shown state structure `pk` is not an index from the state, but identifier sent by server. 

To get client-side index of an element in `state.houses` I should have used `v-for="(hs, idx)...` but I don't use it because of reasons you said and instead use unique id which is sent by server. Assuming values are passed by reference all the code above should be working correctly, I'm just not sure what is faster.